# Use callback to return string

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

I've working on/learning this all afternoon.

Following an example here: http://themainthread.com/blog/2012/09/communicating-with-blocks-in-objective-c.html, I have managed to setup a callback to get the result of an asynchronous call to a web service i have.

The web service takes a key code and the app transforms it and passes it back for authentication.

With my code below, how can I change the method from a void to an NSString that I can call to return my pass code?

```
-(void) showPassCode{
getAuthCodeAndMakePassCodeCompleteBlock callback = ^(BOOL wasSuccessful, NSString *passCode) {
    if (wasSuccessful) {
        NSLog(@"Code is: %@", passCode);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to fetch code. Try again.");
    }
};

[self getAuthCodeAndMakePassCode:@"myAuthCode" withCallback:callback];
}
```

Ideally, I want it to work or look like this:

```
-(NSString *) strPassCode{
getAuthCodeAndMakePassCodeCompleteBlock callback = ^(BOOL wasSuccessful, NSString *passCode) {
    if (wasSuccessful) {
        return passCode;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
};

[self getAuthCodeAndMakePassCode:@"myAuthCode" withCallback:callback];
}
```

Comment: if you change the return value of the method, you have to present a return value synchronously before the scope ends (on each branch). the block runs asynchronously (as you've guessed well), so it will never present a valid string to you synchronously if you pass it over to another method, which will (probably) run it asynchronously (network comm). you ideal concept could not work in this situation without thread sycnronisation, but why would you overcomplicate the thing, if the completion block could have the further procedure? or the original method can have an own completion block as well?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the specifics of your code and how you query the server, I have to imagine it would look something like:

```
-(void)getAuthCodeWithCallback:(void (^)(NSString* authCode))callback
{
    //make server call, synchronously in this example
    NSString* codeReturnedFromServer = [self getServerCodeSynchronous];
    callback(codeReturnedFromServer);
}


//some calling code
[self getAuthCodeWithCallback:^(NSString* authCode) {
    NSLog(@"Code is: %@", authCode);
}];
```

If the method that gets your auth code from the server is asynchronous, it would look something like this:

```
-(void)getAuthCodeWithCallback:(void (^)(NSString* authCode))callback
{
    //make server call, asynchronously in this example
    [self someMethodCallToQueryCodeFromServerWithCallback:^(NSError* error, NSString* code) {
        if (error) { 
            //handle error 
        }
        else
            callback(code);
    }
}
```